# Cookies and browsers

Tags: c#, javascript

when reading a cookie in `Request.Cookies` i should put a special character for the cookie name if i'm using firefox  for example if the cookie name is `seekpunk`  the code should be like this: `Request.Cookies["~seekpunk"]` why do firefox need a special character to determine my cookie name and is this differ from different browsers ??

Comment: What firefox version are you using? Have try to update your version? this is a strange behaviour.

Comment: This is indeed a strange behavior. Have you tried using a different machine's FireFox to test your site? There may be some add-ons in Firefox which may be messing the cookie names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need special character in front of name, normally I just use (indexOf(seekpunk)!=-1) in checking cookies while reading. 
Install firecookie for firefox and check if the cookie name is "~seekpunk" if yes, you code must generate this name somewhere.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Cookies

Comment: thank you for your answer i'll check again to see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: is their a general way to call the cookies without taking in consideration the browser?

Comment: i'm using a c# application i'm creating the cookie using Request.Cookies["example"] but when i try 2 read it back from firefox it retrun null but if i put ["~example"] it return a value i didn't know what is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

javascript

function read() {

```
            var Cookie_Name = "MyTestCookie";

            var sessionValue = null;

            if (document.cookie) {

                var currentDocumentCookie = document.cookie.split(';');
                alert(document.cookie);
                var lengthCookie = currentDocumentCookie.length;


                for (j = 0; j < lengthCookie; j++) {

                    var singleCookie = currentDocumentCookie[j];

                    alert(singleCookie);

                    while (singleCookie.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                        singleCookie = singleCookie.substring(1, singleCookie.length);
                    }

                }

               return 1;

            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

read();

C#
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

```
        // Set the cookie value.
        myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
        // Set the cookie expiration date.
        myCookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(1);

        // Add the cookie.
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

        Response.Write("<p> The cookie has been written.");
```

So it must be your code , I am too busy at work sorry for late reply. Small test,test your self.